# VBA to return all matches from a lookup list

Tags: excel, vba, match, lookup

I am attempting to implement a VBA method to search through a list of names and return all instances of a match from a provided list. The data I am needing returned is in A2:E11. This could be much larger, the sample data I am including is much simpler than the data I am actually trying to use this for. The values that I am trying to lookup is in the range H3:H6. This too could be larger, if there are more lookup values to look for. The output I am trying to get is in J3:N6. Currently I am using a VBA script that can only handle a single lookup value at a time. The method works great, if I only had one lookup value. I was wondering what I would have to change about the script I have below to make it work for what I am trying to do. Again, I am trying to return all matches of a lookup list and copy that data to an "output" range. I am new to VBA, but I believe this is possible. In the past, with a similar problem I used and index match array to return the nth occurrence of a match. This method will not work for me now, because the data set that I am trying to use this for is way too big and takes too long to calculate.

**Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you all!**

```
'1. declare variables
'2. clear old search results
'3. find records that match criteria and paste them

'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOxhRSCfHaw#action=share

Dim name As String 'What you are trying to match to
Dim finalrow As Integer 'Simply a final row helper
Dim i As Integer 'Row counter

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R3:V15").ClearContents 'Clearing the previous output

name = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P3").Value
finalrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row 'This is simply going to a cell way below the data and searching upewards to get the final row

For i = 3 To finalrow 'Row your data starts
    If Cells(i, 1) = name Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
        Range("R100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
Next i

Range("P3").Select

End Sub
```

[image: The excel sheet I am working with]

Comment: So, can we base our pieces of advice or some code to help you on the picture you posted? I mean, have we to deduce that the "lookup list" should exist in the column H:H, starting from the third row? In your code you use a value from P3 cell...

Comment: Yes! Some code would definitely be what I am looking for but advice would be greatly appreciated as well. The picture I have provided, includes my sample dataset, the output I am trying to achieve, and the output I currently have. The code I currently have is for the "right side" of the black line. The lookup values I am trying to find in my data is in H:H starting at row 3 to answer your question.

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer. For big ranges, the fastest way to use arrays and make all process to take place in memory... I will come back with an answer in this regards.

Comment: Thank you!!!! If there is anything else I need to clear up in my question please let me know. The fastest method would definitely be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub testMultipleLookup_NamesSearch()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr As Variant, arrLookUp As Variant
 Dim arrFin As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, t As Long, k As Long

 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'you can use here your sheet to be processed
 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
 arr = sh.Range("A2:E" & lastRow).Value 'put in an array the range to be processed
 ReDim arrFin(1 To 5, 1 To UBound(arr, 1)) 'the initial dimensions able to keep the maximum occurrences
                                           'it is reversed in terms of rows and columns, because only the last dimension can be changed at the end

 k = k + 1 'initialize the variable or arrFin (final) rows
 For t = 1 To 5
    arrFin(t, k) = arr(1, t) 'load the head of the table
 Next t
 arrLookUp = sh.Range("H3:H" & sh.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Value 'Put in an array the Lookup_Names

 For i = 2 To UBound(arrLookUp, 1) 'start iteration of Lookup_Names
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)    'iterate between the array to be processed
        If arrLookUp(i, 1) = arr(j, 1) Then
            k = k + 1
            For t = 1 To 5
                arrFin(t, k) = arr(j, t) 'load all matching row in the final array
            Next t
        End If
    Next j
 Next i
 ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To 5, 1 To k) 'keep only the values to be returned
 'drop the final array in the required range, at once
 sh.Range("R2").Resize(UBound(arrFin, 2), UBound(arrFin, 1)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrFin)
End Sub
```

Comment: @MCTP17 : Glad I could help! In the meantime I commented the code lines which could not be clear enough. If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask... The code should be very fast, even for big ranges... Our purpose here is to teach people asking, at list a few, not only supplying code to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this as hard coding solution, because i do not have excel and i did not try the solution. In your example you process only one look-up key value. What you need to do is that create another loop to consider a range of look-up key values. Something like this:

```
finalrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row 
finalrowformultiple = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1000").End(xlUp).Row

For j = 3 To finalrowformultiple
    name = Cells(j ,8)
    For i = 3 To finalrow
            If Cells(i, 1) = name Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
            Range("R100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            End If
    Next i
Next j
```

this script will consider each look up value in H column instead of one value in P3.
Hope this helps.